# Show that $A = \{0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4,...,1/n...\}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I write down my gull answer for this question, however my main question is on this part:"Therefore for each number 1/n of this sequence we can associate one open set $G_k$ such that 1/k $\in G_k". How can I be sure that for any **arbitrary** open cover I can pick one open set that has one of these elements?

Fell free to point out if something else is wrong..

Show that $A = \{0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4,...,1/n...\}$ is compact

Let first review our definitions:

**Finite** - A set B is finite if it is empty or if there is a bijection with domain B and range in an initial segment ot N.

**Compactness** - A subset K of a metric space X is said to be compact if every open cover of K contains a finite subcover. More explicitly, the requirement is that if $\{G_a\}$ is an open cover of K, then there are finitely many indices $a_1, ..., a_n$ such that K $\subset G_a1\ \cup...\cup G_an$

**Open Set** - E is open if every point of E is an interior point of E

**Interior point** - A point p is an interior point of E if there is a neighborhood N of p such that N

proof (Direct Method)

Consider the open cover of the set a to be G = $\{G_a\}$ and let $G_0$ be the open set such such that 0
$\in G_0$. By the definition of open set, we know that there is a B(0, r) with r $>$ 0 around 0, such that 1/$n_0$ $\in$ B(0, r) = (0 - r, 0 + r) $\subset$ $G_0$ for some $n_0 > 1/r$ in the naturals. By the definition of finite, we know that the sequence $\{1/n\}$ for n $>$ $n_0$ have a finite number of elements. Therefore for each number 1/n of this sequence we can associate one open set $G_k$ such that 1/k $\in G_k$ considering that this sequences is finite the union of $G_0$ with all open sets $G_k$ for k $>$ 0 is a finite open cover.

Comment: Easier if you can use compact iff closed and bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea and answer are correct. More generally, if $X$ is a metric (topological) space and $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $X$ with $\lim_n x_n = x$, then $\{x\}\cup \{x_n: n \ge 1\}$ is compact.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for the generalization

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of open cover, $A\subset\bigcup G_\alpha$. So, if $a\in A$, there is ome $\alpha$ such that $a\in G_\alpha$.

And your proof is fine.